# Axis Labels Disappear With Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, plotting, labeling

I have a `ListPlot3D` with custom axis labels that I am scrolling with `Manipulate`. My issue is that the axis labels scroll away as the plot is scrolled. The commands below reproduce the problem that I am having.

Thanks,

Edmund

```
tickLabels = {{1, ""}, {2, ""}, {3, ""}, {4, ""}, {5, "lv1"}, {6, 
""}, {7, ""}, {8, ""}, {9, ""}, {10, "lv2"}, {11, ""}, {12, 
""}, {13, ""}, {14, ""}, {15, "lv3"}, {16, ""}, {17, ""}, {18, 
""}, {19, ""}, {20, "lv4"}, {21, ""}, {22, ""}, {23, ""}, {24, 
""}, {25, "lv5"}, {26, ""}, {27, ""}, {28, ""}, {29, ""}, {30, 
"lv6"}, {31, ""}, {32, ""}, {33, ""}, {34, ""}, {35, "lv7"}, {36, 
""}, {37, ""}, {38, ""}, {39, ""}, {40, "lv8"}, {41, ""}, {42, 
""}, {43, ""}, {44, ""}, {45, "lv9"}, {46, ""}, {47, ""}, {48, 
""}, {49, ""}, {50, "lv10"}};

Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[
  Table[i + j RandomReal[{1, 5}], {i, 50}, {j, 15}][[window - 9 ;; window]],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "value"}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, tickLabels[[window - 9 ;; window]], Automatic}], 
  {window, 10, 50, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the actual range of `y` coordinates using `DataRange`.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[
  Table[i + j RandomReal[{1, 5}], {i, 50}, {j, 15}][[window - 9 ;; 
     window]], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "value"}, 
  DataRange -> {{0, 15}, {window - 9, window}}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, tickLabels[[window - 9 ;; window]], 
    Automatic}], {window, 10, 50, 1}]
```

[image]

As it stands, the default range for the `y` coordinates (`Range[10]`) is used in your original code.

Alternatively, you can use the form `ListPlot3D[{{x1, y1, z1},{x2, y2, z2}, ...}]` providing the three coordinates of each data point:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[
  Join @@ Table[{j, i, i + j  RandomReal[{1, 5}]}, {i, 50}, {j, 
      15}][[window - 9 ;; window]],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "value"}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, tickLabels[[window - 9 ;; window]], 
    Automatic}], {window, 10, 50, 1}]
```

Comment: Many thanks, kguler.  There are so many options that I don't even know what is possible.

Comment: @Edmund, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.